# Yielding self to rspec test inside each loop yields last known state

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm writing some rspec tests for some web-pages.  One of the pages contains several links that I want to test as a group.  So my test looks something like this

```
require 'spec_helper'

t = Page.new
t.test do |t|
  describe 'a thing' do
    it 'should not be last' do
      t.title
    end
  end
end
```

So when I call `t.title` I am actually calling that on the the following Page object being yielded (by itself) down below.

and my Page object looks like this

```
class Page

  attr_accessor :driver

  def initialize()
    @driver = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
    @home = ''
    @driver.goto(@home)

  end

  def visit(url)
     @driver.goto(url)
  end

  def title
    @driver.title
  end

  def test
    @subpages.each do |page|
      visit(page)
      yield self  
    end
  end

end
```

So now when I run rspec, what ends up happening is the test will run as many times as I expect it to, however it runs each time it yields the object in the state it's in during the final iteration of visit.  So it's not really testing the pages the way I want it to, it's testing the last page in the list.

Am I incorrectly using `yield` or `self` here?  It seems pretty straightforward: pass the test as a block to the Page object's test method and have it run the test on itself.

Any tips?  I'd like to be able to keep all the tests clean, and all the logic in the page object, but this is hindering me from doing so.

Comment: Are you sure your `Page#test` method is being called? It looks like you're just calling `Test#test`

Comment: Sorry let me correct that.  I'm sure.  If I do `yeild self.title` it will actually print the correct title.  It seems to be the case that calling `yield self` is the problematic part.

Comment: Glad you figured it out

Comment: I haven't really, I'd have posted an answer.  Inside of `Page#test` things happen as they should, the each method cycles through its contents, but strangely it appears that `yield self` doesn't happen until the end of the cycle, exactly as many times as the loop ran.  Is this the default behavior of `yield self`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the scope of a given file, RSpec examples/tests don't get executed until they all have been defined. You're iterating through the page defining all these examples, but RSpec is collecting and not executing them until the iteration is complete, at which time the value of `t` remains unchanged and corresponds to the final state of the page.